# What is the RFC definition of an HTTP message header?

Tags: http, http-headers, grammar, rfc, bnf

I read the [grammar](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616) as:

```
   message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
   field-name     = token
   field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
   field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
                    and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
                    of token, separators, and quoted-string>
```

However, it is not very precise:

> <the OCTETs making up the field-value
> and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
> of token, separators, and quoted-string>

How do I interpret that? What is the formal grammar version of `field-content`?

Comment: This is one interpretation of the grammar 
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/d0d0bf7fc5534c1304011b8f78843f0155b560f4/http/http.g4#L93 which you would have to check. Although in ABNF (a formal definition of BNF that has an RFC spec), people still abuse the rules. I ran into a similar problem just a few weeks ago with Microsoft's definition for Excel functions.